# Nyquist Plot from Bode Plot

Tags: bode-plot, nyquist-plot

How do I know the value at which the Nyquist plot crosses -180 degrees from looking at the Phase plot from the Bode?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nyquist plot is at -90 degrees when the phase lag is -90 degrees. This occurs over the frequency range during which the slope of the magnitude curve on the bode plot is truly -20dB/decade.

The -20dB/ decade slope will start to become steeper than -20dB/decade from about a decade below that double pole.

Comment: But how do I know the value at which it crosses -180 degrees is -10?

Comment: You don't, at -180 degrees the gain is 10. You've marked the gain as 20dB (=10) on the bode plot at -180 degrees which is why the system is unstable. ie. The gain is greater than 1 when the phase is -180 degrees.

Comment: The minus in -10 on the Nyquist plot represents 180 degrees lag. So the gain is 10 on the bode plot but is shown as -10 on the Nyquist plot.

Comment: Thanks, how do I know that at a frequency of 10^5, the dB gain is 20 dB?

Comment: If the 1Hz gain is 10^6 (120dB) then dropping at 20dB/decade leaves 20dB at 10^5Hz. But I don't understand how you've arrived at your bode plot, either the low frequency pole frequency or the double pole frequency of 10^5. I'd be pleased to try and understand if you're willing to explain. I assume that A & B represent the open loop transfer function and the feedback transfer function which when multiplied together give the loop transfer function, Aol*beta otherwise known as G(s)H(s).

Comment: The loop gain is simply A*B where A = G/s and B is a ratio.